# Getting error in ProfileController.php as : Error Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input' not found in laravel 5.4 ...Help me resolve this error

Tags: laravel-5

my ProfileController.php file is below:

I have already add aliases in my config/app.php as 'Input' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input::class,
still it's not working.

Answer (score 0):

After laravel 5.2 Input:: is replaced with Request::

try using

```
Request::
```

to import Request class use

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```